# android NotificationCompat.Builder is undefined

Tags: android, notifications

when i try to set my Notification code into button 
it always gives me the error in this part

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =**new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)**

[[ The constructor NotificationCompat.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined ]]

how i can solve this problem ???

```
Button button9= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {


        ///////////My Notification//////////////////////////        
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("I'm astm  loooooooool")
        .setContentText("Hello baby to my world!");
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself) (ResultActivity)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int mId = 0;
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
        ///////////End Notification//////////////////////////
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys for helping me   [[ No one gives me any answer looooooool ]]

i get the answer with my self 
just define the **NotificationCompat.Builder** as Final and it worked well

^__^

```
        ///////// my Nine button (set Notification) //////////
    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("I'm astm  loooooooool")
    .setContentText("Hello baby to my world!");
    Button button9= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    final TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        ///////////My Notification//////////////////////////        
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself) (ResultActivity)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int mId = 0;
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
        ///////////End Notification//////////////////////////

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `this` with `getBaseContext`

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I changed:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
```

with:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context)
```